# MailApp.sendEmail Error Message - "do not have permission to call sendEmail"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, triggers

When I change something in my spreadsheet, the `onEdit()` trigger runs, and I can see all the msgbox's that I put in my code.

My function stops at this line

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

I never see the message 'Email sent!', and get an error in the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT:

> You do not have permission to call sendEmail

If I run the script directly in the script editor, everything works fine...

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var sheetname = sheet.getName()
      var AcCellRange = sheet.getActiveCell()
      var AcCol = AcCellRange.getColumn()
      var AcRow = AcCellRange.getRow()

      if (sheetname=="Questions/Réponses") {
        //Browser.msgBox(AcCol+' / '+AcRow)
       //liste d'instructions
        //Boucle si les colonne sont comprise dans le range
        if ((AcCol==3) || ((AcCol==7))){
          //Browser.msgBox(AcCol)
          if (AcRow > 7){
            //Browser.msgBox(AcRow)
            sendEmails()
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {}
    }    
function sendEmails() {
      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails')
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ListCourriel');
      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails2')
      var sheetDonnee = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Questions/Réponses');
      var RangeProjet = sheetDonnee.getRange(1, 3)
      var NoProjet = RangeProjet.getValue()
      var RangeProjet = sheetDonnee.getRange(4, 3)
      var ProjName = RangeProjet.getValue()
      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails3')
      var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
      var LastRows = sheet.getRange(1,4)
      var numRows = LastRows.getValue();   // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails4')
      //Permet d'aller cherche les info de la ligne active
      var ActiveCellRange = sheetDonnee.getActiveCell()
      var ActiveRows = ActiveCellRange.getRow()
      var NoLigne = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,1)
      var sDep = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,2)
      var sDate = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,4)
      var sInitiale = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,5)
      var sQuestion = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,3)
      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails5')
      var rDate = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,9)
      var rInitiale = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,10)
      var rReponse = sheetDonnee.getRange(ActiveRows,7)

      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails6')
      var subject = 'Modif. Question/Réponse - Projet: ('+NoProjet+') '+ProjName;
      var message = "No Ligne : "+NoLigne.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Reponsable : "+sInitiale.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Date : "+sDate.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Question : "+String.fromCharCode(10)+sQuestion.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+String.fromCharCode(10)+"************************************"+String.fromCharCode(10)+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Reponsable : "+rInitiale.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Date : "+rDate.getValue()+String.fromCharCode(10)+"Réponse : "+String.fromCharCode(10)+rReponse.getValue()
      //Browser.msgbox(subject)

      Browser.msgBox('SendEmails7')
      for (i in data) {
        Browser.msgBox('SendEmails8')
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
        Browser.msgBox('SendEmails9')
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        Browser.msgBox('Email sent')
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using `Browser.msgBox()` for debugging purposes, there is another option.  You can use 'Logger.log()`, run the code, then VIEW the LOGS.

Comment: Have you VIEWed the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT?  What does it state at the end?

Comment: Use the debugger, and set a break point on the `MailApp.sendEmail()` line, then run the debugger, and when the code pauses, view the values for `emailAddress, subject, message`.  What are they?  [Google Documentation - Break Points](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Ok thank you for the tips!! If I look at the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT I can see this error message : [15-03-16 08:48:34:543 EDT] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call sendEmail (line 44, file "Code") [0.139 seconds total runtime]

Comment: OK I found it, I have to instal a trigger, for those who have the same problem check this : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 15):

The permissions are different when running a **SIMPLE** `onEdit()` trigger. By contrast, there is an **INSTALLABLE** trigger. Here is the documentation for simple trigger restrictions:

[Google Documentation - Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)

The documentation states:

> They (a SIMPLE trigger) cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization

You need to set up an *installable* trigger to be able to send the email.

In the **EDIT** menu, choose, **CURRENT PROJECTS TRIGGERS**.

Name your function something different than `onEdit`.

Comment: I have an other probllem, I have a File name 'MASTER', I put my code in this file, and each time we start a new projet, someone take the file 'MASTER', rename it and use the new file. My problem is that it seem that each time we copy the file 'MASTER' I need to redo all the processe to add my trigger to the project?? Is there a way that I only have to do it in the MASTER file?? Thank you!

Comment: How I solved it: I have already installed the trigger. However, as I added another service in my function, I needed to save the trigger again so that it will ask for my permission for other services.